# SQL update after choosing a MAX from some AVERAGEs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, max, average

I have 2 tables with same columns but different data. I need to compute the average of a column in one table ( with some filters ) and to choose the MAX of them. Then to put that value in the 2nd table.
I've built so far this query:

```
UPDATE st16 
    INNER JOIN st17 ON st17.parent = st16.uid 
    SET 
        st16.p1 = SELECT MAX(
            (SELECT AVG(st17.p1) FROM st17 WHERE st17.parent = st16.uid AND st17.row = st16.row)), 
        st16.p2 = SELECT MAX(
            (SELECT AVG(st17.p2) FROM st17 WHERE st17.parent = st16.uid AND st17.row = st16.row))
```

but I get this error: "#1111 - Invalid use of group function".
Any ideas? Thanks!

Sample data ( first is st17, and below is st16 ):

```
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| uid                              | parent                           | fen                                                                                                            | p1                  | p2                  | row |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| ee95b564f2b3fa1573b451d8f4e00f5d | bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | QS7D8D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/6D5D3D2DKSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD | -10.481481481481481 |  10.481481481481481 |   1 |
| 691ed545dd5375cb3e75f0b8d032534b | bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | QS7D6D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/5D3D2DKSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D | -10.481481481481481 |  10.481481481481481 |   1 |
| b6e2a3f4ea51c8e6638a2cc657bf3511 | bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | QS7D5D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/3D2DKSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D | -10.481481481481481 |  10.481481481481481 |   1 |
| 0dbe5038d01e457e4f65415ac081d0dd | bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | QS7D3D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/2DKSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D | -10.481481481481481 |  10.481481481481481 |   1 |
| ca1e85058ed8294d60a9922d36f8c1fa | bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | QS7D2D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/KSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D | -10.481481481481481 |  10.481481481481481 |   1 |
| e85179f395ba8e441ff7b1544e05404c | c75eb9315dee4e3b42fb52e8cd509910 | QS7DJS/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CKS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/TS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2DAS |  -9.703703703703704 |   9.703703703703704 |   1 |
| eb3c352febe8ff25f375032bbb6cc5d7 | c75eb9315dee4e3b42fb52e8cd509910 | QS7DTS/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CKS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2DASJS |  -9.703703703703704 |   9.703703703703704 |   1 |
| 69f06801edf9b3cf669df56dc9152271 | c75eb9315dee4e3b42fb52e8cd509910 | QS7D8S/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CKS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2DASJSTS |  -9.703703703703704 |   9.703703703703704 |   1 |
| 5f78082dd3aee8b51bf096286df5e4e7 | c75eb9315dee4e3b42fb52e8cd509910 | QS7D5H/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CKS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2DASJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H |  -9.703703703703704 |   9.703703703703704 |   1 |
| 7ee50e8aa1afd3af703b3a5b3cdf3cf8 | c75eb9315dee4e3b42fb52e8cd509910 | QS7D3H/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CKS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2DASJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H |  -9.703703703703704 |   9.703703703703704 |   1 |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+

+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+-----+
| uid                              | parent                           | fen                                                                                                            | p1 | p2 | row |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+-----+
| bc5ef0d66b3bde08b0ba35a91412c058 | 9e123e356e468b847d4493cf55809fcd | QS7D/4H9HQH4D4S/6H8HTHJHKH/4CAS/9S9D7CJC9C/6C8CQCKCAC/KSJSTS8S7S6S5S3S2SAH7H5H3H2HTC5C3C2CADKDQDJDTD8D6D5D3D2D |  0 |  0 |   1 |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: You can't use a subquery as an argument to an aggregation function.  Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  It is unclear (at least to me) what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, I put here some excerpts of my data tables: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102498471/sql.jpg

As is visible there, highlighted in yellow is a partial sample of data I need to process:
in table st17 I need to compute the average of the rows highleted ( they have row = 1 ). There are potentially other 1 or 2 more such sets, but with row = 2 and row = 3. I need them averaged too. Then I need to pick the MAX of the 3 averages and update table st16.p1 at row that has the uid highlighted with that MAX value.

Comment: @xybox . . . You should put the data and desired results in the question.  First, the pictures you have are unreadable.  Second, the link may expire at any time.

Comment: I don't see why do you think the image is unreadable ( obviously you need to see it at 100% zoom ) or that it could expire since it's ona dropbox. However, I can't post yet the image into the body of the question ( 10 reputation points are required and I'm newly signed up ). Anyway... thanks for the help.

Comment: @xybox . . . Put the data in the question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff mentioned, you can't pass a subquery to an aggregate function such as `MAX()`. Another problem that you will likely run into: you cannot select from the table you are updating in MySQL. So something like this

```
UPDATE st16 
SET 
    st16.p1 = (SELECT AVG(st17.p1) FROM st17 JOIN st16 ON st17.parent = st16.uid WHERE st17.row = st16.row ORDER BY AVG(st17.p1) DESC LIMIT 1), 
    st16.p2 = (SELECT AVG(st17.p2) FROM st17 JOIN st16 ON st17.parent = st16.uid WHERE st17.row = st16.row ORDER BY AVG(st17.p2) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

will **not** work, unfortunately. You might just want to break this into multiple queries; that is, retrieve the maximum averages first in a `SELECT`, then ship those results in a second, separate `UPDATE`.